# realtime api feed - how to get new comments?

Tags: facebook, real-time, feed, facebook-fql

I made it to subscribe to the realtime api and retrieve update messages telling me the uid and time when the item changed. But how do I get the corresponding post/comment. I tried to use the fql but unfortunately there seems to be a bug in the fql when using updated_time.

This is my query:
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, updated_time, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND updated_time >= "pushTime"

where pushtime is the time I got from the realtime notification.

It works for getting a standalone(no comments) post but as soon as there are comments it does not work. When I go through all posts and check the updated_time I can find the correct post.
My only solution for the time being is to iterate over all posts until i find the post where updated_time == "pushTime".
Anyone another solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored previous comments then retrieve the last comment ID you have stored and use that to query facebook for comments with an ID higher than that.